# $E[1/X]$ For an Exponential Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $5$. How would I compute $E[1/x]$? If I use the definition of expected value, I get:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{5e^{-5 x}}{x} dx$

I've not the slightest clue as to how I would integrate this. I was told the answer is simply $\frac{1}{1/ \lambda} = \lambda$, but I don't know how this could be.

Comment: $\lambda=1/\Bbb E(X)$ is the *harmonic* mean of $1/X$.

Comment: I don't know who told you that but $E(1/X)$ is in general **not** equal to $1/E(X)$.

Answer (score 3):

Taking $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and taking any $\epsilon > 0$ you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(1/X) 
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x} \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} e^{-y} \ dy \\[6pt]
&\geqslant \int \limits_0^{\epsilon } \frac{1}{y} e^{-y} \ dy \\[6pt]
&\geqslant e^{-\epsilon} \int \limits_0^{\epsilon } \frac{1}{y} \ dy \\[6pt]
&= e^{-\epsilon} \Bigg[ \int \limits_1^{\epsilon } \frac{1}{y} \ dy  - \int \limits_1^{0} \frac{1}{y} \ dy \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= e^{-\epsilon} \Big( \ln (\epsilon) - \ln(0) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= e^{-\epsilon} \Big( \ln (\epsilon) - (-\infty) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \infty. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Thus, the expected value does not exist (i.e., it is infinite).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{5e^{-5 x}}{x} \, dx = 25 \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u} \, du$$
but the integral does not converge since $\frac{e^{-u}}{u} \ge  \frac{1}{2u}$ as $u \to 0$. So $E[1/X]$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have pointed out it is not possible to integrate this.

To get the expected value, I would consider the relationship between the exponential and gamma distributions. An exponential is a gamma distribution with an α of 1 and λ = λ.

Then we can find the expectation using the gamma distribution in a similar manner to [top two answers on this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198595/expected-value-of-gamma-distribution).

$$
E(X^m)= \frac{\Gamma(a+m)}{\lambda^{m}\Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
In our case α=1, m=-1, so

$$
E(X^{-1})= \frac{\Gamma(1-1)}{\lambda^{-1}\Gamma(1)}= 
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\lambda}} = \lambda
$$